Pyspark Merge - ambiguous column / reference
I'm encountering an issue when trying to merge a delta table with a transformed data frame. The error message indicates that the column contract (variable BK = 'contract') is ambiguous. This column exists in both the sink and transformed_df, and I've correctly aliased these tables. Despite this, the error persists.
Within my ETL function, I'm performing a hash operation on the contract column, so I cannot rename it directly. To work around this, I tried renaming the column on transformed_df after the ETL function and just before the merge operation. However, I still receive the same error regarding ambiguity.
Is there a way to resolve this ambiguity issue when merging these two data sources, considering the hash operation in the ETL function? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.
transformed_df = ETL(batch_df, all_new_batch_timestamps_df, BK, SK, columns_to_track)

transformed_df = transformed_df.withColumnRenamed(
    f"{BK}", f"new_{BK}"
).withColumnRenamed(f"{SK}", f"new_{SK}")

sink_delta = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, sink_path + "/delta")

merge_condition = f"lhs.process_time = rhs.process_time AND lhs.{BK} = rhs.new_{BK} AND lhs.{SK} = rhs.new_{SK}"

## merge 1
(
    sink_delta.alias("lhs")
    .merge(transformed_df.alias("rhs"), merge_condition)
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
    .whenMatchedUpdateAll()
    .execute()
)

I am getting the following error: [AMBIGUOUS_REFERENCE] Reference contract is ambiguous, could be: [lhs.contract, rhs.contract]. SQLSTATE: 42704
I have tried renaming the column after the ETL call but this raises the same error.
